# Ratio of terms in simple geometric sequence appears inconsistent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

The series I'm working with is defined as the sum from 1 to infinity of $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1+2^n}{3^n}$. The first terms of the sequence as defined are:

- 1
- 5/9
- 1/3
- 17/81

The trouble I'm having is that the ratio between those terms is not consistent:

- $\dfrac{5/9}{1} = r = \dfrac{5}{9}$
- $\dfrac{1/3}{5/9} = r = \dfrac{3}{5}$
- $\dfrac{17/81}{1/3} = r = \dfrac{17}{27}$

Since $r$ is inconsistent I can't find the sum of the series.

I feel like I'm probably missing something really basic here but I can't figure it out for the life of me. Any pointers?

Comment: I am sorry what do you mean by ratio of terms?

Comment: I mean a ration as in (a_n+1)/(a_n), where a_n is a term in the sequence and a_n+1 is the next term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a geometric series.

Why?

Observe that the $k$th term of the sum is given by
$$a_k = \dfrac{1+2^{k}}{3^{k}}$$
so that the ratio of the $(k+1)$th term to the $k$th term is
$$\dfrac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}=\dfrac{(1+2^{k+1})/3^{k+1}}{(1+2^{k})/3^{k}} = \dfrac{1+2^{k+1}}{1+2^{k}} \cdot \dfrac{3^{k}}{3^{k+1}}=\dfrac{1+2^{k+1}}{1+2^{k}}  \cdot \dfrac{1}{3}$$
which is not constant (because it depends on $k$). Thus, this series is not a geometric series.

However, there is a way to solve this problem.

Observe that 
$$a_k = \dfrac{1+2^{k}}{3^{k}}=\dfrac{1}{3^k}+\dfrac{2^k}{3^k}=\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^k+\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^k\text{.}$$
Thus, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^k + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^k$$
This is a sum of two geometric series.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thank you. The thing that still trips me up though is that my textbook (and [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+(1%2B2%5En)%2F(3%5En),+n+%3D+1)) list the sum of the series as 5/2. If the series isn't geometric, how could they find a sum?

Comment: @AlexJohnson See the edit.

Comment: Wow, how embarrassing. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexJohnson No problem. Believe me, it's not as trivial as I might make it seem.

Answer (score 0):

i think your sum is equal to $$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1+2^i}{3^i}=\frac{1}{2} 3^{-n} \left(-2^{n+2}+5\ 3^n-1\right)$$